# Is 'to avoid company' a correct expression?

Tags: phrase-meaning, articles, phrases, phrase-choice

I am trying to convey the next message:

> Being an introvert doesn't mean [avoiding company/to avoid company].

Is it correct to use *'to avoid company'* in the meaning of *'to be alone, to keep yourself away from company'*? 
Should I use an article before *'company'*?

---

Since it's uncountable, I am supposed to not use an indefinite article to describe a general idea.

> company (U) - the fact of being with a person or people, or the person or people you are with

Comment: There's no grammatical rule saying you *can't* randomly switch verb forms, but most native speakers normally wouldn't. Choose either ***Being** an introvert doesn't mean **avoiding** company*, or ***To be** an introvert doesn't mean **to avoid** company*, to maintain stylistic consistency.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you for the point. Is *'Being an introvert doesn't mean to avoid company'* grammatically valid as *'Being an introvert isn't to avoid company'* is? Are both statements correct?

Comment: **Being an introvert** refers to an existential/psychological state of mind, a person's character.  *to avoid company* refers to an action in the abstract. Making the semantic leap required to make sense of your utterance is not difficult, but *Being an introvert does not mean to avoid company* is actually saying that the psychological state or character trait doesn't *equate to* the act of avoiding company. There are a number of ways to express the idea more clearly and idiomatically than that.

Comment: Andrew - like I said, ***choose either***. It's nit-picking to claim one is "better" than the other - and for your exact context (and most similar ones) it's unrealistic to claim there might be some *semantic* difference between using the infinitive or the continuous participle. There are contexts where a careful / competent writer would definitely prefer one ***or*** the other, but that's a matter of stylistic choice, beyond the scope of ELL. But do take note of the "consistency" principle (again, not a *rule*, just a stylistic guideline / tendency).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with **to avoid company** in and of itself.

> An introvert is not someone who wishes to avoid company.
>
> Being an introvert does not mean  wanting to avoid company.
>
> Being an introvert does not mean you want to avoid company.

Comment: I was a bit confused because Grammarly suggested putting either 'a' or 'the' before 'company' (here and other contexts)

Comment: Grammarly is wrong.  It doesn't know what you're trying to say. It's just some algorithms.

Comment: They have an uncountable definition of the noun, so I thought they might have been able to figure it out.

Comment: Grammarly "thinks" you mean something like this: *It's best to avoid a company when reviews by dozens and dozens of former employees say it is a terrible place to work.*   Does it also reject "Extroverts enjoy company"?

Comment: Yes, it does. It expects the definite article :)

Comment: I understand that by 'company' it considers 'an organization/group' which are countable nouns

Comment: The original passage was *"I am an introvert with a bit pessimistic views of things.
It doesn't mean that I avoid company/am avoiding company. Actually, I do love working with creative and smart people around me."* The second sentence bothers me. How to make the whole excerpt clear and idiomatic?

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko: The second sentence is fine. *It doesn't mean that I avoid company.*  However, "with a bit pessimistic views of things" is not idiomatic.

Comment: How can we improve that?

Comment: Better to ask a separate question on that, as it can be complicated, and I have to leave for a few hours in any case. I'll be back online later today.

Comment: OK, I will add a separate question and share the link with you here. Thanks for the help with this issue.

Comment: The link: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/177761/53961