# Does the sentence sound "I am an introvert with a bit pessimistic views of things" natural?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, idiom-request

> I am an introvert with a bit pessimistic views of things.

As pointed out by [@Tᴚoɯɐuo](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/10264/t%E1%B4%9Ao%C9%AF%C9%90uo) in [this thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/177753), the part *"with a bit pessimistic views of things"* doesn't look idiomatic.

I am an introvert, right. But I am not a pessimist to the extent of seeing only bad parts of a situation/thing. That's why I used 'a bit'.

I ponder over the negatives of an issue before moving to its positive sides. That's why I introduced a subordinate clause (not sure how the part *', with...'* is called) instead of directly saying

> I am an introvert and pessimist.

It seems too direct and inaccurate, isn't it?

I was wondering how we could improve it.
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"with a bit pessimistic view of things" is not idiomatic.

**To make it idiomatic, you might use:**

- with a rather pessimistic view of things
- with a somewhat pessimistic view of things

Or you could leave out the adverbs rather and somewhat or even use others: **very, slightly, openly,** etc., to qualify your pessimistic view.

Comment: Could you clarify why I should prefer the singular form of “a rather pessimistic view” over the plural “rather pessimistic views”?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Because, one has a view of things. Not views of things. You might have views (images) of products in a catalogue, though.

Comment: I can have different opinions on a matter, but can't I have several views on it?

Comment: Wouldn't you agree, in general, and regardless of the language, people can have views or opinions on things. An individual usually has a view of things; when view of things means: society or life.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is a valid subject complement **a bit old** is not an idiomatic adjective phrase coming before the noun.

> Chef, this fish is a bit old. It's unacceptable. <sup>idiomatic</sup>
>
> Chef, this a bit old fish is unacceptable. <sup>unidiomatic</sup>
>
> His views are a bit pessismistic. <sup>idiomatic</sup>
>
> His a bit pessimistic views are set out in chapter 3. <sup>marginal?</sup>

Comment: is the part *"view**s** of things"* alright?

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko: The phrase **of things** is a factor here. **He has pessimistic *views*.** is grammatical and idiomatic but a native speaker would say **He has a pessimistic view of things** since that refers to his "pessimistic worldview" which is monolithic in its pessimism, not fragmented.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> I ponder over the negatives of an issue before moving to its positive
>   sides.

I wonder if it would be more accurate to describe you as [skeptical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skeptical) (or a skeptic):

> marked by an attitude of doubt or a disposition to incredulity either
>   in general or toward a particular object

whereas a [pessimist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pessimist) is

> a person who is inclined to expect poor outcomes

You aren't inclined to expect a poor outcome, but rather inclined to consider all facets of a situation before accepting it.

With that said, it would be idiomatic to say:

> I am an introvert and also a bit of a skeptic.
>
> I am introverted and also a bit skeptical.
>
> I am a skeptical introvert.
>
> I am an introvert who tends to be skeptical of things.
>
> I am an introvert who takes a skeptical view of things.

You could substitute pessimist/pessimistic for skeptic/skeptical in any of the examples above.

Comment: In my opinion, a pessimist is a person who emphasises the bad parts first (like me) and not willing to look for the advantages (not me). On the other hand, a skeptic associates with doubt, unwillingness, or disbelief. Anyway, thanks for the answer, I appreciate it.